# why WCF service stop working every 20 mins?

Tags: multithreading, wcf

I am newbie of wcf and mulit-thread, and I write a wcf service hosted in IIS7, in this service there is a long running task (System.Threading.Tasks.Task) which will probably be going to run 20 hours.

But this wcf service always stops to work every 20 minutes.

I make the wcf send email to me when application_stop and application_start is running. Therefore, I receive a email when it start run, and then after 20 minutes, I receive the email show that the service stop.

**I really cannot figure out why this happen, why the service stop work every 20 minutes.**

**Does the wcf services stop every 20 minutes, or the Task thread stop every 20 minutes?**

**Will any configuration of IIS7 impact wcf running time?**

I try to set the receiveTimeout to a every large time amount, and I use asych call to invoke wcf in client side, but this does not make help.

Guys, I really need help, many thanks.

Following code belongs to a website which calls this wcf service

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMailingService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:92/MailingService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMailingService" contract="MalingService.IMailingService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IMailingService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS application pool idle default timeout is 20 minutes. You can configure application pool idle timeout by the below steps, which I picked from this article - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(WS.10).aspx

- Open IIS Manager.
- expand the server node and click Application Pools.
- On the Application Pools page, select the application pool for which you want to specify idle time-out settings, and then click Advanced Settings in the Actions pane.
- In the Idle Time-out (minutes) box, type a number of minutes, and then click OK.

As rerun said, IIS host is not the best for your scenario, WAS on a Windows Service would be a better option.

Comment: thanks Sachin, I try to set the idle time to 5 minutes to if the wcf service stop in 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks Sachin, I change idle time to 0 to make this wcf service keeping running. I know this not a ideal solution for this case. But I currently have to choice this method. I plan to move this into windows service in the future. But how to make a web site to call this windows service? Do you have any idea about this? Thanks.

Comment: This and other "side-effects" of app pools are some of the reasons I would always recommend hosting production level WCF services yourself, in a controlled Windows NT Service.

Comment: @jeff chen you can host wcf services in a very similar manner. See the link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx for an example

Answer (score 3):

IIS is a poor choice for hosting a long running task.  If it is at exactly 20 minutes I would think that iis is shutting down the owner thread but that is speculation.  I would really suggest moving to a windows service wcf hosting environment.

Comment: thnaks rerun. But if I host this wcf service into windows service, how the website call this service?

Comment: Exactly the same way.  The host is independent of how it makes itself available to other hosts

Answer (score 1):

I use a cheap cron job service service to hit a handler on my app every 5 minutes. This helps keep the pool alive. If you don't want to move away from IIS, this is a quick and "dirty" fix.

Comment: Thanks NovaJob, I also get this idea before, :P